# Adding external graphs libraries

Tags: php, graph, jqplot, atk4

I'm learning how to integrate ATK4 with an external graph library.

Anyone, has some recommendations about this ?

thanks.
Alejandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trevor has published integration with jqPlot:

http://sterlingend.co.uk/

Integration with any other JavaScript plugin is done very easily. Here is example for Highcharts:

https://github.com/atk4/atk4-addons/blob/master/misc/templates/js/ui.highcharts.js

It might not work right away, but will give you idea how to move forward.